# Let $T$ be exponential with parameter $\lambda$. Let $X$ be discrete defined by $X= k$ if $k \leq T < k+1$, $k=0,1,2,\dots$. Find the pdf of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

To be honest, I am lost on this question. Here is what I have so far: 
$$ \
F_T(t)=- e^{-\lambda t}=P[T\le t]
\ $$
$$ \
P[X=k]=P[k\le T \lt k+1]
\ $$
I am not sure how to go about finding the pdf for $X$.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks for the response Tom. Here is what I have now:
$$ \ 
P[X \le k]=P[\{X=k\}\cup\{X=k-1\}\cup...\cup\{X=0\}]
=P[\{k \le T \lt k+1\}\cup\{k-1 \le T \lt k\}\cup...\cup\{0 \le T \lt 1\}]=P[T \lt k+1]=F_T(k+1)=e^{- \lambda (k+1)}=F_X(k)=>f_x(k)=\lambda e^{- \lambda (k+1)}
\ $$
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could give their thoughts on my answer.

Comment: Asked again [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027563/let-t-be-exponential-with-parameter-%CE%BB-let-x-be-discrete-defined-by-x-k-if-k%E2%89%A4tk/3027828#3027828) with answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $P[k\leq T < k+1] = F_T(k+1) - F_T(k)$ where we are using the fact that $P[T=k] = P[T=k+1] = 0$.